# Sending a path of a file to google drive

Tags: java, selenium, google-drive-api

I am trying to send a path of a file to the "file upload" button on a cloud app like google drive or dropbox using selenium. I was able to locate the element "file upload" and to click on it and then the "file upload window" is open so I am able to upload a file manually but this is not what I want. What I would like to do is to send the path to the "file upload window" without the need to click the "file upload" button.

[image: box ui]

As you can see in the picture, if I press the Files button in order to upload a file then a pop up window is open.
[image: popup window]
I want to be able to send the path directly to the popup window without the need of open it.
Is there a way to achieve it?
Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to add it to google drive *on the internet*? Why not just add it to the google drive folder? That would automatically update your drive online.

Comment: what do you mean by add it to the google drive folder? basically i need to create a test that acts as a real user and i need to upload a file to the google drive on the internet and this is where i stuck since i cannot sendKeys to the right element because i am not able to find it using the inspector

Answer (score 0):

You can use autoit here to upload the file in google drive , Click using selenium and once upload window opens then add autoit code to upload file.

```
public void uploadfilechromeforgdrive(String path, String fileName) throws InterruptedException {
    Logger.info("Started uploading " + fileName + " in Progress");
    String dllPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "src" + File.separator + "test"
            + File.separator + "resources" + File.separator + "lib" + File.separator + "jacob-1.18-x64.dll";
    File file = new File(dllPath);
    System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath());
    AutoItX x = new AutoItX();
    x.winActivate("Open");
    x.winWaitActive("Open");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    x.controlFocus("[CLASS:#32770]", "", "Edit1");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    x.ControlSetText("[CLASS:#32770]", "", "Edit1", path + fileName);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    Logger.info("The sent file name " + fileName);
    x.controlClick("[CLASS:#32770]", "", "Button1");
    Thread.sleep(50000);
    Logger.info("Started uploading " + fileName + " completed");
}
```

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).